# How to retrieve the limited collection of related entities?

Tags: java, jpa-2.0

Suppose, we have an entity **User**, which has many **comments**.
It is possible to do so:

```
List<Comment> = user.getComments();
```

But this will load **all** the comments of the user.
How should we retrieve just first 10 for example?
Is the anything similar to:

```
List<Comment> = user.getComments().setOffset(0).stLimit(10).getResultList();
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard Java way to do it (and I'm pretty sure that JPA providers have the functionality to back that up) is:

```
List<Comment> = user.getComments().subList(0,10);
```

**Reference**

- [`List.subList(from, to)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29)

---

Or you can use the extremely verbose JPA 2 `CriteriaQuery` API:

```
CriteriaQuery<Comment> cQuery =
        entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder()
                     .createQuery(Comment.class);
cQuery.select(cQuery.from(Customer.class)
                     .get(Customer_.comments));
List<Comment> comments = 
        entityManager.createQuery(cQuery)
                     .setFirstResult(0)
                     .setMaxResults(0)
                     .getResultList();
```

Comment: I know that. But before I get the sublist, JPA will load **all** the coments of some user: you should agree that it wil be a disaster, if a user has for example 1mil comments

Comment: @userXXX *JPA will load all the coments of some user* Nope. if you use lazy loading, the provider will load a proxy List that creates a new proxy List for the subList(). The actual query will only be executed once you access the list entries. But AFAIK that's not officially defined in the JPA standard. If I read the Hibernate source right, Hibernate does that, but there's no guarantee. @Cristian's way is certainly safer, but it's also more ugly

Comment: @BarsMaster as I said, your mileage may vary, but give it a try, at least

Comment: i'll log the mysql queries and see, which ones will be sent

Comment: _Or you can use the extremely verbose JPA 2 CriteriaQuery API:_ I will still need a method for every model that has relations with the other entities

BTW, I logged the queries: unfortunately subList() is called after **all** the entities (comments) are retrived

Answer (score 2):

You should limit this in the query using `LIMIT` and not in the code.

Eg:

```
    SELECT comment.id, comment.name FROM comment WHERE comment.name =:username 
ORDER BY comment.id DESC LIMIT 10;
```

OR you can use `setMaxResults` method from jpa: documentation [here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#setMaxResults%28int%29)

Eg:

```
Query query=em.createQuery("SELECT st FROM Student st WHERE st.sroll > ?param");
query.setParameter(param, 100);
query.setMaxResults(3);
List stuList=query.getResultList();
```

Comment: So there no such built-in capabilities to achieve that, like in Ruby On Rails3?

Comment: As I understand I have to write the additional method for each entity to get the limited results?

BTW, what does that mean: @username?

Comment: @user717336 I did not say that it's not possible in java, (like Sean pointed out) the key thing is that it's better to do this in sql and not load all the data and do the filtering in the code. About your second question- `:username` it's just a parameter like in Named Queries ( http://www.javabeat.net/tips/108-how-to-use-named-parameters-and-named-query-i.html )

Comment: I know that it is possible, but we have to load **all** the collection, don't we?
So back to my question: will it be ok to create a method which will return the limited collection of objects for every entity (model)?

Comment: @BarsMaster Well, it depends. I do not use such a way because I use NamedQueries and put the limit there if I need it. In most of the cases I do not need limit because I filter with `WHERE` all what I need.

Comment: I knew thah too, but you should write it for every entity and it is a pitty ((